# Как запустить браузер гугл хром через selenium Python, так чтобы открылась страница не пустая, а со всеми установленными плагинами и авторизацией

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

подскажите пожалуйста, пишу автотест на Python, Selenium.
страница запускается первым шагом,  но выходит страница - новой вкладкой, он пустой, как будто в режиме инкогнито(но нет), отдельным открытым окном, где я не авторизован и не установлен ни один плагин.
(при этом гугл даже вручную не дает авторизоваться)
Как запустить страницу так, чтобы я цже был авторизованным как обычно, и были установлены все мои плагины.

```
import time

from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium import webdriver

def autotest():
        # настройка браузера
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
        options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\chromedriver.exe')
        # ссылка на рабочий стенд
        driver.get("https://test123.ru")
        driver.fullscreen_window()
        time.sleep(2)
        driver.maximize_window()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    autotest()
```

После запуска запускается новая вкладка хром, как будто с 0 в режиме инкогнито.
(без автооризации, плагинов, закладок и тд)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Добавьте свой код, однако.

Comment: @СергейКох
Код добавил)
+ скрин

Answer (score 0):

попробовать передать куки

```
options = selenium.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument(cookie_path)  # C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Comment: что то без изменеий.
ввел в виде добавления аргумента
Добавил элемент

Comment: ```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled")
    options.add_argument("--cookie_path")
    options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-logging"])
    driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```



вот элемент.
либо я не так добавил.

Comment: options.add_argument("C:\\Users\\{user}\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")

Comment: options.add_argument("C:\\Users\\bulra\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
-к сожалению все без изменений открывает в том же режиме.

Comment: я попробовал еще один метод 
user-data-dir
в итоге запускается браузер в том самом режиме, но 
--user-data-dir=chrome-data _ выходит ошибка в модальном окне браузере 
Браузер Google Chrome не может выполнять операции чтения и записи  в каталоге данных chrome data.
Если укажу корень папки профиля, то выходит ошибка в пайчарме
 (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Stacktrace: